# Change TextColor in ListView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

P.S I have ListView and TextCell in XAML but I want to change textColor
 in my code

I am doing DarkMode for my app and I have next issue:
Cell - TextCell

`Cell.TextColor = Color.White;` shows me an error : Cell doesn't exist in the current context

How can  bind it to my context or change text color. Please tell me any way to do that....

**UPD:**

Creating the cell:

I made it with XAML

```
     <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20" x:Name="Main_View2">
            <ListView x:Name="Main_Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Planets}" ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
             <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="labelTable" TextColor="#FF851B">

            </TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              </ListView>

      </StackLayout >
```

Comment: Show the code creating the `Cell`. Beside that, you should use ViewModel with bindings in your xaml.

Comment: I upgraded description. Look

Comment: Also show your ViewModel and item model of the Planets property

Answer (score 2):

**Way-1** Give Color as Below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Planets}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Way-2** : Define one property in your Model(Planets) and provide a Color there, then bind it as below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Planets}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding MyTextColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Way-3** : Define one property in your ViewModel for TextColor then bind it like below

```
Color myTextColor = Color.White;
public Color MyTextColor
{
    get { return myTextColor; }
    set { SetProperty(ref myTextColor, value); }
}


<ListView x:Name="Main_Menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Planets}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference Main_Menu}, Path=BindingContext.MyTextColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: SetProperty(ref myTextColor, value); shows an error.

Comment: It's how I implement the propertychange. You need to replace that line based on how you implement the propertychange. Check for other properties you defined and make change as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I can do that with resources:
`

App.Current.Resources["textColor"] = Color.Black;`

and in XAML:

```
TextColor="{DynamicResource Key=textColor}"
```